# “I said that I heard the word.” Is the word “that” a relative pronoun here?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> I said the word that I heard.

This is indirect speech and the word ''that'' is a relative pronoun.

But what about the sentence:

> I said that I heard the word.

Is the word ''that'' a relative pronoun here ?

If so then why ? If not then why not ?

Answer (score 1):

> I said **that** I heard the word.

*That* here is not a relative pronoun but what is called a *subordinating conjunction* by traditional grammarians and a *subordinator* or *complementizer* by many contemporary grammarians.<sup>†</sup> It marks the clause which it introduces as subordinate, usually acting as a complement of a constituent in the clause to which it is subordinated.

<sup>†</sup> <sub>In fact, there are grammarians who hold that *that* is never a "relative pronoun" but **always** a subordinator/complementizer—but I think that this is an unnecessarily narrow distinction. A single term may be employed in some contexts to serve multiple functions.</sub>